# How to retrieve the value sent by a $.ajax function in my php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I get the following error on the .php page. Notice: Undefined index: name

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: "GET",
    data: ({name: "James"}),
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

I am trying to get the value sent from the data object in the test.php file as follows:

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
     echo $_GET['name'];   
} else {
    echo "Not working";
}
```

Comment: Nothing in that PHP script should be able to cause an undefined index notice.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you get if instead of doing your if else logic if you did just: `echo json_encode($_POST)`

Comment: Can you log/var_dump and check what is inside $_POST?

Comment: This sounds odd but try removing the `()` in the `data` key

Comment: @Taplar I get the same output. That is, Notice: Undefined index: name... on line 23.

Comment: @Taplar I get the same output. That is, Notice: Undefined index: name... on line 23.

Comment: If all you are doing is the echo I suggested, then there wouldn't be 23 lines of code.  There'd only be one.  You got some other error going on.

Comment: @ SamHecquet doing a log/var_dump, I get NULL.

Comment: @Taplar I did not put all the contents of the file here. The rest of the file contains commented code of things I was trying to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Taplar Doing this, echo json_encode($_POST), a get an empty array []

Comment: Can you verify that the ajax request you have in this question is exactly as you have it in your code, and if not, update it to reflect what it is.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xmr5L03e/  If you open the network tag, run the fiddle, and inspect the ajax request, you'll see that it is putting the fields on the request as form data, so this ajax request, as you provided it, is valid as is.

Comment: @ Taplar I can confirm that the request that I posted is exactly as I have it in the code.

Comment: @AndreReid Out of curiosity, does the Browser's console display any errors?

Comment: If that is true, then the data is being put on the request as form data which will be picked up by the $_POST variable by php.  However you are saying that it printed back an empty array, which would signify that the endpoint did not get that data.  There is a disconnect between those two statements.  You should check your network tab to find the ajax request that is made and verity that the data is being put on it.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious - do you actually declare `$name` anywhere? I mean in the code you provided you are checking if `$_POST['name']` is set and echoing `$name`...

Comment: @Oliver Baumann No errors are being displayed in the console.

Comment: I am not sure why I am not being directed to the test.php page

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
data: {name: "James"},
```

Instead of

```
data: ({name: "James"}),
```

Comment: Attempting to do this, data: {name: "James"}, I am still getting Undefined index name.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's something wrong with the jQuery part. Try to make the data a valid JSON object `data: {"name": "James"}` (notice how `"name"` is enclosed in quotes):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"name": "James"},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Removed `dataType`. As Taplar pointed out, this is linked to the returned data.

Comment: You're very right. I still think the error `Undefined index: name` has to do with the unquoted `name` key though, so I've left my updated answer.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle I put in the OP comments, the ajax request as he provided it works fine.  But he has provided that echoing the $_POST is empty, so I suspect there is a discrepancy in the ajax example he provided, and what he is actually doing.

Comment: @Taplar I tied this. It has not change or affected the results that I have been getting.

Comment: I check the network tab. But nothing was being displayed. However, I made a change to the .php file, I changed the $_POST['name'] to $_GET['name'].
I also made a change to the ajax code, I changed the type:"POST" to type: "GET".

Presently, echo json_encode($_GET) displays the object that was sent. However, I am not directed to the /test.php?name=James page.
{"name":"James"}

Comment: @AndreReid you shouldn't be directed anywhere, an AJAX-request won't trigger navigation to a URL in the browser (which is what you seem to want (now?)...?)

Comment: @ Oliver Baumann That is correct. How do you propose I go about triggering a navigation to a URL in the browser

Comment: Sorry for the cheek, but there are plenty of solutions to your "new" problem on this site. Please use the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize for accommodate your data

**example :**

```
var serializedData = 'name=James';

$.post('test.php', serializedData,
  function (enumData) {
    console.log(enumData);
  }
);
```

**hope** this helps you. cheers :)

Comment: jQuery automatically turns objects into param strings if you do not tell it otherwise.

Comment: @Taplar for this solution, the .php file should remain the same right.

Comment: $.ajax already does this for you, regardless of what your backend does.  This solution is suggesting you do something explicitly that the library already does by default.